# Cygwin DenyHosts daemon-control file: no such file or directory error

Tags: python, cygwin, daemon, denyhosts

I have been trying to figure out this error and searched everywhere with no luck.
I have installed DenyHosts on Cygwin and also the DenyHosts daemon but when I try to start the daemon by typing:

```
cygrunsrv -S DenyHosts
```

I get the following error in my DenyHosts.log file:

```
C:\Program Files\Python33\python.exe: can't open file '/usr/share/denyhosts/daemon-control': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I have checked the above path to daemon-control and the file is there.
Any ideas?